# Showing the last 5 comments that belong to a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, posts and comments, and i am trying to show the last 5 comment titles.

```
<%= Post.limit(5).order('created_at desc') %>
```

gives me the last 5 posts.

How do i get the last 5 comments and just the titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting just last 5 comments, you can use this

```
Comment.limit(5).order('created_at desc').select(:title)
```

Showing the title of the post, it looks like that you want to retrieve the last 5 comments of a post.

You can get this way:

```
<% Post.limit(5).order('created_at desc').each do |post| %>
  <% post.comments.select(:title).order('created_at desc').limit(5).each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

There are two problems:

- You're accessing the model directly from View. You should do it from
  Controller
- There is N + 1 problem. You can solve it by [eager loading associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

*Note: I couldn't test these but I guess they will work or will, at least, give you idea.*

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for:

```
Comment.select(:title).order('created_at desc').limit(5).map {|c| c.title}
```

This will give you an array of titles for the last 5 comments created. If you need other attributes, either add them to the select method called (`Comment.select([:title, :owner])`), or remove the select and fetch all comment attributes.

Comment: I now realize that returns the last 5 comments for all posts. Any idea how to limit it to just one post?

Comment: @user2759575 Yeah, try `@post.comments.select(:title).order('created_at desc').limit(5).map {|c| c.title}`. Also, as HungryCoder says, you should probably be loading this in your controller instead of the view and assigning it to an instance variable. It just separates the query and display concerns a bit more.